# Is it possible to drag and drop a full size image from a website to the explorer, where only a thumbnail is shown

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to drag and drop a full size image from a website to the explorer, where only a thumbnail is shown.

I want to show a gallery with thumbnails in a website and it should be possible to download the full size image just by drag and drop it to the window explorer  for example.

[Edit]: Because of the size of the images I could not just show the full size images smaller.

I will check the drag und drop events.

Comment: You can have your gallery be the full size images scaled down to thumbnail size (explicitly set height and width to something small). When user drags one to explorer it will save the full size file.

Comment: It might be possible to intercept the drag events and swap in the full resolution image at some point but its not something I've looked into so can't be sure. I'd suggest binding to the drag events and seeing what gets triggered when you drop an image into the file system.

Comment: Possibly swap the img src attribute to point to the full size image on mouse down, set an explicit heigh and width on the img tag to prevent it resizing when you switch to the full size src.

Comment: @NicholasHirras I like the idea to just replace the src attribute

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, I realy like the simple approach to change the src attribute.

```js
window.jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    let img = "#imageTest";
    function revert() {
        $(this).attr("src","https://placehold.it/200x200");
    }
    $(img).on('mousedown', function () {
        $(this).attr("src","https://placehold.it/2000x2000");
    });
    $(img).on("drag", revert)
    $(img).on("mouseup", revert);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id='imageTest' width="200px" class="image-preview" 
 src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="preview">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little example I came up, just to show what option there is using some jQuery.
The user needs to select which images they want to get in a higher quality.

```js
$( ".trigger" ).click(function() {
  $(".image-preview").attr("src","https://placehold.it/2000x2000");
  $(this).slideUp('slow');
});
```

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.image-preview {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
 }
 
.trigger {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  padding: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-container">
  <img class="image-preview" src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="preview">
  <span class="trigger">Get full size</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but not exactly what I am searching for.